# Add keyword exclusions to indexOf keyword matching in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

Currently matching keywords that then performs an actions. How can I incorporate the exclusions list into the function below?

```
<!-- Product names include Apple iPad, Acer Iconia, Lenovo Thinkpad plus Generic, No Brand-->
<h1 id="pbtitle">Apple iPad 3</h1>
<div class="install_option" style="display:none;">              
    <div style="box-sizing:border-box; float:left;">
        <a href="https://www.example.com/acc" target="_blank">
            <h3 style="font-weight:bold;">Would you like to view accessories?</h3>
        </a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var options = ['Acer','Apple','Lenovo'];
var exclusions = ['Generic','No Brand'];
var text = $("#pbtitle").text();

options.forEach( function( element ) {
    if ( text.indexOf( element ) != -1 ) { // if its NOT -1 (-1 = not found)    
      $('.install_option').css('display','block');  // then we found it .. do your magic
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If text has to be substring of inclusions/exclusions then

```
if ( options.indexOf( text ) != -1 && exclusions.indexOf( text ) == -1 )
```

You need to try

```
var options = ['Cooker hood','Island','Ceiling','Downdraft','Integrated','Canopy','Telescopic','Cabair','Bathroom'];
var exclusions = ['Filters','Filter','Kit','Foil','Ducting','Switch','Transformer','Silencers', 'Install'];
var text = $("#pbtitle").text();
if ( options.indexOf( text ) != -1 && exclusions.indexOf( text ) == -1 )
{
   $('.install_option').css('display','block'); 
}
else
{
   $('.install_option').css('display','none'); 
}
```

Comment: exclusions should be `== -1`

Comment: Doesn't work yet. Does the exclusion need adding to the forEach?

Comment: options.forEach && exclusions.forEach ?

Comment: @merch89 No, you need to iterate options and exclusions only if their elements are substring of `text`. If the text entered by user is substring of these two array's elements, then you simply need to use the if statement given by me above